# Windows Phone7 Development: Selecting target SDK(OS) version

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Bit confusing in selecting the target version in Windows phone7 Application development.

In my Windows phone7 app I need to use a light weight relational DB Which didn't introduce with version 7.0 but SQL CE with 7.1 version.

The problem is if I select the target version as 7.1, then the devices which came up with windows phone7 OS 7.0 will not be able to install this.

But I heard that all the devices that came with windows phone7 OS version 7.0 is upgradable for windows OS version 7.1 for free. If this is the case then if I select the development SDK version as 7.1, then will all the windows phone7 devices be able to install this?

Like to know which will be the best Target version in this case to select, before I start developing. Any guidance/ Idea is highly appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is best to target 7.1 for everything. Most (if not all) of the early adopters with 7.0 will have been upgraded to 7.1 by now. I have not seen any evidence of a 7.0 device for any of our app in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

All first generation Windows Phone devices with 7.0 OS are entitled to a free upgrade to the 7.5 OS version (codename "Mango", SDK is version 7.1)

So, I can think of no reason why you should just use the 7.1 SDK; also, most of the toolkits for Windows Phone development have made their 7.0 version obsolete and are working only with 7.1, so that's one more a reason to go with 7.1!